# How to periodically write new rows in a Cassandra table to another table

Tags: database, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am trying to copy rows from a Cassandra table to another table (in Cassandra or may be to Oracle) continuously for running different dashboard queries. The source Cassandra table will be having inserts into it with a volume of about 6 million per day and the rows have a TTL of 30 days. I am using Spring-data-Cassandra in my application. I have checked the following options but none of them look fine to me. My Cassandra table is defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE event_status (
      code text,
      status text,
      app_id text,
      correlation_id uuid,
      db_ts timestamp,
      next_app_id text,
PRIMARY KEY ((code, status),app_id, correlation_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER by (app_id ASC, correlation_id ASC);
```

1. Materialized views in Cassandra: Not generally recommended as per some documentation especially because of my volumes.
2. Cassandra triggers: Not recommended again due to performance issues.
3. Having a separate column which marks the row as read: This is not recommended in Cassandra as writes are very fast and it is counter-intuitive to do an update with every write.
4. Marking the timestamp as read in some other table and periodically reading this table and then querying the source table for rows after this timestamp. This is also an issue since I am thinking of having multiple threads do this work to scale out.

Is there any best practice around this in general for any database and in particular in the Cassandra world?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a use case that's a good fit for tapping into Cassandra CDC. If you haven't already, check out the early developer access version of the [DataStax CDC connector for Apache Kafka](https://www.datastax.com/press-release/datastax-announces-change-data-capture-cdc-connector-apache-kafka). It allows you to move data between DSE, Apache Cassandra and Kafka clusters.

The DataStax Apache Kafka connector is now also freely available to Apache Cassandra users (see [the announcement here](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/12/tools-for-apache-cassandra) for details). Cheers!